# Get nth child with multiple lists

Tags: css

Is there any way to select every fifth `li` descendant of the div in the following?

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five (this one)</li>
    <li>Six</li>
    <li>Seven</li>
    <li>Eight</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Nine</li>
    <li>Ten (and this one)</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I've tried using `nth-of-type`, but that only works for siblings.

Comment: as far as I know, it is impossible with CSS, you probably want to do it in js

Comment: Interesting problem. Of course you can make a css counter that counts the li items while disregarding the ul's - see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/vu3dq0k6/) - but AFAIK there is no way to check what the current value of a counter is in CSS, so that's a dead end.

Comment: I've implemented a CSS counter that counts every `li`, but there's no way I can find to then select every fifth one. In the end I just wound up creating a class for each fifth `li` when I create the doc.

Comment: @SamDutton If nobody else comes along with a good solution, you can always post that as an answer. "This is impossible" is a valid answer too.